# Filling a sk_buff with content of recieved frame

Tags: linux-kernel, network-programming, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, systems-programming

I'm writing an kernel network module and when I receive an Ethernet DIX frame, which is represented as continuous sequence of bytes, I have to properly put all content of recieved packet into sk_buff. How should I do it?

I tried to build and transfer my frame like this

```
    struct sk_buff* skb = netdev_alloc_skb(dev,len);
    skb_reserve(skb,len);
    void* temp = skb_push(skb,len);
    memcpy(temp,data,len);
    netif_rx(skb);
```

But in wireshark I see that Linux treat it like a Linux cooked capture rather than Ethernet
[sniffed frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anDxh.png)

Answer (score 0):

[http://vger.kernel.org/~davem/skb_data.html](http://vger.kernel.org/%7Edavem/skb_data.html)

One incorrect thing is that you are running skb_reserve for data length.
skb_put extends the used data area of the buffer so you are doing it twice. Also try with skb_put.
Try code below:

```
netdev_alloc_skb(dev, len + NET_IP_ALIGN); 
skb_reserve(skb, NET_IP_ALIGN);
skb_put(skb, len); //skb_putpoints to the start of skb data
memcpy((void*)skb->data, data, len);
```

Or you can try this (not tested):

```
netdev_alloc_skb(dev, len + NET_IP_ALIGN); 
skb_reserve(skb, NET_IP_ALIGN);
skb_put_data(skb, data, len); //skb_putpoints to the start of skb data
```

NET_IP_ALIGN -> you can read about it here https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4.1/source/include/linux/skbuff.h#L2588

You can also compare the pointer returned from skb_put and skb_push and see the difference between these two.

Comment: My fault was that I did not initialise my network device as an ethernet device. After adding ether_setup(dev); to the setup function the issue has gone.